# Selenium's Open function waits until what?

Tags: unit-testing, selenium

When I call the Open("[some URL]") method in Selenium, it waits until all resources (images, CSS, JS) are downloaded.  But how does it know that the browser is done requesting resources?

Here's my snippet of driver code (in C#):

```
DefaultSelenium selenium = new DefaultSelenium(
    "localhost", 4444, "*iexplore", "http://www.stackoverflow.com");

// open my profile page
selenium.Open("http://stackoverflow.com/users/111934/jeff-meatball-yang");
```

The URL above is for example only.  In the case where I have an AJAX call wrapped in a very long delay in a `setTimeout()` triggered in the body `onload` event handler, Selenium won't actually wait for that AJAX call before continuing...  I have to manually tell Selenium to wait using `WaitForPageToLoad(timeout)`.

So how does Selenium detect when a normal page (without AJAX) is finished loading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it waits for location.href to be available, which means that if you have AJAX running after this point you will also need to use waitForCondition.

```
selenium.open("http://www.example.com/");
selenium.waitForCondition("var value = selenium.getText('id=pageLoadStatus'); value == 'Loaded'", "60000");
```

Below is the current page load detection code from Selenium core:

```
this.recordPageLoad = function(elementOrWindow) {
    LOG.debug("Page load detected");
    try {
        if (elementOrWindow.location && elementOrWindow.location.href) {
            LOG.debug("Page load location=" + elementOrWindow.location.href);
        } else if (elementOrWindow.contentWindow && elementOrWindow.contentWindow.location && elementOrWindow.contentWindow.location.href) {
            LOG.debug("Page load location=" + elementOrWindow.contentWindow.location.href);
        } else {
            LOG.debug("Page load location unknown, current window location=" + this.getCurrentWindow(true).location);
        }
    } catch (e) {
        LOG.error("Caught an exception attempting to log location; this should get noticed soon!");
        LOG.exception(e);
        self.pageLoadError = e;
        return;
    }
    self.newPageLoaded = true;
};
```

Comment: Thanks Commander Dave.  :)  Can you point me to the file or SVN address where you found this?

Comment: You're welcome! http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/selenium-core/trunk/src/main/resources/core/scripts/selenium-browserbot.js#83

Comment: You can also use [`waitForElementPresent`](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0.1/reference.html#storeElementPresent) after calling `open`.

Answer (score 1):

@Dave Hunt, [you're correct that `recordPageLoad` is called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460481/seleniums-open-function-waits-until-what/1460564#1460564), but it merely logs the page-load location (`location.href`) if available and sets `self.newPageLoaded = true`, the value returned by `isNewPageLoaded` and, thus, by `doOpen`.

`isNewPageLoaded` is called in [`selenium-api.js`](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/trunk/javascript/selenium-core/scripts/selenium-api.js) by `_isNewPageLoaded` <= `makePageLoadCondition` <= `doOpen`. And, `doOpen` is invoked after Selenium IDE runs the [`open`](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0.1/reference.html#open) command.

The relevant trace is:

`doOpen` calls (moving to [`selenium-browserbot.js`](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/trunk/javascript/selenium-core/scripts/selenium-browserbot.js)) `openLocation` => `getCurrentWindow` => `_modifyWindow` => `modifySeparateTestWindowToDetectPageLoads` (which according to the comment above it, waits "by polling continuously until the document changes and is *fully* loaded") => `pollForLoad` => `getReadyState`.

`getReadyState` returns the [`document.readyState`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#current-document-readiness) (`rs`), and `pollForLoad` waits until `rs == 'complete'`, i.e., until the page has fully loaded, images and all.

[Ace Ventura](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tuhPPOXnyKo) explains it better than I can.

---

P.S. @Dave Hunt, thanks for your [Selenium IDE Flow Control script on GitHub](https://github.com/davehunt/selenium-ide-flowcontrol). It came in handy! :)