# Selenium waitForDOMToLoad()?

Tags: dom, selenium, readystate

[Selenium's `open` command implicitly waits for the whole page to load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460481/seleniums-open-function-waits-until-what/5054759#5054759), including images, etc.

How do I just wait for the DOM to load, like [jQuery's .ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) method?

Currently, I'm using [waitForElementPresent](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0.1/reference.html#storeElementPresent), but is there a better alternative?

Comment: Any reason you want to start interacting with the page before it's ready? Is it just to run tests faster?

Comment: Yes. I'm using Selenium to automate tasks on a photo website I don't own, and the automation, as in most cases, doesn't depend on the images being loaded.

Comment: How are you exercising the Selenium api? Are you using Selenium IDE?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may try to do the following

1. Tweak the selenium source code to stop it raising page reloaded flag.
2. Use custom command or getEval to check if the dom is loaded and proceed.